# How to word wrap <input type="textarea"

Tags: input, textarea, word-wrap

I have created a form that pulls data from a database. The data is displayed correctly but I have a field that contains 200 characters and I need to have all the text displayed but is displaying on one line. The field type is 'textarea' but does not wrap. The code and css I am using is:

The css:

```
.update input[name="update_descript"] {
display: flex;
height: 150px;
width: 600px;
```

}

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">      
    <label for="descript">Description</label>
    <input type="textarea" name="update_descript" placeholder="ride description" value="<?=$ride['rideDesc']?>" id="descript"></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the  tag does not need nor does it work with the  tag. Just use the  tag.